# How to prevent debugger from repeating in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, netbeans-6.9

I just got xDebug working with Netbeans and I've noticed that it repeats through the same file over and over.

For example if I am debugging a page called index.php it will go through it and then start all over again. The page is never loaded up in the browser...

How can I stop that from happening?

Comment: I'm a little new.  Should this be on superuser instead of stack overflow or are IDEs considered the domain of stack?

Comment: It seems like he's asking how to efficiently debug a particular PHP program.  I think this belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at the very first PHP line (i.e. not in an explicit loop that you can see) and then hit continue after breaking there, does it keep breaking at the same line again and again?

Comment: There are no loops in the php file, it's just that the debugger keep going through the file over and over (loop)

Comment: @k to the z... You're too new....

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your break where do you want to start inspect (`CTRL+F8` or double click in the line you want to break). a icon break will appear.
2. Do your debug (`CTRL+F5`).
3. In Debug Mode click continue (`F5`), it will stop at the line you break (point 1)